# How to create asp.net Custom web controls event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, custom-controls

I have a `OptionRadioButtonList` class extends `RadioButtonList` web controls:

```
public class OptionRadioButtonList : RadioButtonList
{
    public EventHandler SelectionChangeEventHandler;
    public OptionRadioButtonList()
    {
        RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
        AutoPostBack = true;
        Items.Add(new ListItem("YES", "YES"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("NO", "NO"));
        CssClass = "rbList";
    }
    protected virtual void OnSelectionIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectionChangeEventHandler != null)
        {
            SelectionChangeEventHandler(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This class is used in a aspx.cs file like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // more code here
    OptionRadioButtonList rblist = new OptionRadioButtonList();
    rblist.SelectionChangeEventHandler += new EventHandler(mainQuestion_rblistHandler);
    LocalPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(rblist);   // this is a placeholder in aspx file
    // more code here
}
// RadioButtonList Event handler
protected void mainQuestion_rblistHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RadioButtonList currentRblist = (RadioButtonList)sender;
   if (currentRblist.SelectedValue.Equals("YES"))
   {
      // do something
   } 
   else
   {
      // do something else      
   }
}
```

So the UI part works fine, but when I change the selection of the yes no `radiobuttonList`, the `Page_Load` function gets called, but not `mainQuestion_rblistHandler` can not be reached when I set a break points there. I am not sure what I did wrong, can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `OnSelectionIndexChanged`. Override the base `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method and call `OnSelectionIndexChanged` in there.

```
public class OptionRadioButtonList : RadioButtonList
{
    public EventHandler SelectionChangeEventHandler;
    public OptionRadioButtonList()
    {

        RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
        AutoPostBack = true;
        Items.Add(new ListItem("YES", "YES"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("NO", "NO"));
        CssClass = "rbList";
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = SelectionChangeEventHandler;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```